# Получение целой части дроби в SymPy

Tags: python, python-3.5, sympy

Добрый день. Если мне нужно сосчитать значение выражения, то я использую:

```
symplify('420/16', rational=True)
```

В данном случае, ответ будет `105/4`. Но мне нужно выделить целую часть дроби. Как мне это сделать?

Comment: Во-первых, у функции `simplify` нет key-word параметра `rational`. Во-вторых можно обойтись без sympy: `420 // 16` будет равно  26. В третьих, при сильном желании можно сделать так: `int(symplify('420/16'))`, результат - 26

Comment: Я просто привел пример. Окей, `symplify('4201/16')`. Должно получиться `262 9/16`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может так?

```
def f(formula):
    a = simplify(formula)
    if not a.is_rational or a.is_integer:
        return a
    i,r = divmod(*a.as_numer_denom())
    return '{} + {}/{}'.format(i, r, a.q)
```

Примеры:

```
In [132]: f('45/3')
Out[132]: 15

In [133]: f('sin(x)')
Out[133]: sin(x)

In [134]: f('4201/16')
Out[134]: '262 + 9/16'

In [135]: f('420/16')
Out[135]: '26 + 1/4'
```